# Scroll to top the page when enter text on input with ng-model of angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scrolltop, angular-ngmodel

I have a form with two fields, user and password, both field are binded with ngModel

```
<form method="POST" name="loginForm" novalidate class="loginForm">
    <input ng-required="true" ng-model="loginRequest.UserName" class="textControls userCtrl" type="text" name="UserName" id="id_username" />
    <input ng-required="true" ng-model="loginRequest.Password" type="password" name="Password" id="id_password"/>
    <button  type="submit" id="submitLogin" class="blueBtn">Ingresar</button>
</form>
```

My problem is when typing first two letters on each field in mobile devices, the page is scrolled to top in iphone losing focus of the field. this behaviour disapear when remove ng-model to the input fields.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to diagnose if you include enough code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @buzzsaw I can't reproduce this error on fiddle sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario looks like the form submit triggers the page refreshing. By default if you don't manually stop event propagation, it will refresh the page if you use form submit.

If you use form, just add an `ng-click` directive to your `<button>`, and call `event.preventDefault();`.

If you use `$http` service to post your form data, you can avoid this automatically.

Comment: the scroll is trigger aeach time that type a character on each input textbox

Comment: Add this `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` to your input. So it updates the model only on Blur.

Comment: The problem is not update ng-model, the problem is that the page scroll to top when update the model :S

Comment: How about this?
add `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` to your `input`, and add `ng-change=handler(e)`, and in your controller, `$scope.handler = function(event) { event.preventDefault(); };` . updateOn Blur is optional.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Comment: oops typo. `ng-change=handler($event)`;